# Threaded Program to compute Fibonacci numbers

Tags: c++, multithreading, fibonacci

I'm trying to write a program in C++ to compute the Fibonacci series. I create a thread that does the calculation and output. But nothing in my for loop seems to get executed. Can anyone have a look at my code and tell me what I might be doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std; 

//iterative with output
DWORD WINAPI fib3(LPVOID param){
double u = 0; 
double v = 1;
double t; 
int upper = *(int*)param;

for(int i = 2; i <= upper; i++){
    cout << v << " "; 
    t = u + v; 
    u = v; 
    v = t; 
    cout << "testing" << endl; 
}
    cout << v << " "; 
    return 0; 
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

cout << "This will compute the fibonacci series.\n" << endl; 
bool done = true; 
double x; 
DWORD ThreadId; 
HANDLE ThreadHandle; 

while(done){

    cout << "Enter a number: "; 
    cin >> x;

    if(x == -1){
        cout << "\nExiting" << endl; 
        return 0; 
    }

    ThreadHandle = CreateThread(NULL, 0, fib3, &x, 0, &ThreadId); 

    if(ThreadHandle != NULL){
        WaitForSingleObject(ThreadHandle, INFINITE); 

        CloseHandle(ThreadHandle); 
    }

}

return 0; 
}
```

Comment: You receive the coveted Obfuscation Award (third class) for your choice of `done` as variable name.

Comment: Not directly related to your problem, but calculating Fibonacci numbers using a loop is a rather inefficient method.  Is there a reason you using that method?

Comment: I know I can do it recursively. But I just thought it would be easier to output each number this way?

Comment: Recursively isn't a good way to go either (it is only really useful academically when teaching about recursion).  There are formulas that calculate Fibonacci numbers.  See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsFibonacciNumberFormula.html

Comment: @ZacHowland I would hesitate to use this formula, since it involves floating-point arithmetics prone to rounding errors. See https://wandbox.org/permlink/Kitb6mbkRODXbElS, where the result is different for, e.g., Fib(90) when using `double`. IMO, a better solution would be to use a table of exactly calculated Fibonacci numbers, since standard integer types can represent only few of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're passing the address of a double to CreateThread, then you try to treat it as an int * in the thread func. Change `double x;` to `int x;`

Comment: Thank you for the speedy response. That did it :-D